# Combining .when() method in $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

In my code, the paths, "/" and "/A" call for the same template and controller.  Is it possible to include multiple routes for the a single .when() method?  If so, how can these routes be combined?

```
$routeProvider.
    when("/", {
        templateUrl: "templates/A.html",
        controller: "AController"
    }).   
    when("/B", {
        templateUrl: "templates/B.html",
        controller: "BController"
    }).   
    when("/A", {
        templateUrl: "templates/A.html",
        controller: "AController",          
    }).
    otherwise({ 
        redirectTo: '/' 
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about redirecting the `/A` request?

```
    when("/A", { redirectTo: '/' } ).
```

Answer (score 1):

Might you consider a parameterized route? If `A` is not static, that would be the way to go. You'd have something like this:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/:A?", {
        templateUrl: "templates/A.html",
        controller: "AController"
    })   
    .when("/B", {
        templateUrl: "templates/B.html",
        controller: "BController"
    })   
    .otherwise({ 
        redirectTo: '/' 
    });
```

Comment: yeah, I didn't mean to suggest my routes are variable with the use of "A" and "B".  My routes are static "/", "sign_up", "log_in", etc.  How would parameterized routes help?